# Mysterious caching bug with knitr and matchit (package MatchIt)

Tags: r, caching, simulation, knitr

I have a problem with knitr caching an R chunk containing a call to the matchit() function in the package MatchIt, using the "genetic" algorithm implemented in the packages Matching and rgenoud : this chunk is executed at *each* and *every* compilation. This is a double pain :

- The genetic algorithm uses simulations ==> slight variations in results (my student will faint at the notion of a change on the third "significant" decimal of a p.value...)
- Damnably time consuming (propensity score matching is harder than you think, especially on small samples).

I have managed to reduce this to a "minimal reproducible example" which is not *that* minimal Rnw-wise (about 5 Kb .Rnw file including a serious bit of preambule), and needs quite unminimal data (80 Kb .csv data) and a small .bib file. Anyway, there seems to exist no way to attach files to a stackoverflow question...

I tried to reduce the dependency of data files by adding an explicit dependency on the MD5 sums with the cache.extra option. No success

I also specified explicit dependencies with dependspon(). No luck.

I also asked this question (with example an data) to Yihui Xie (got no answer, but the guy might have a PhD to defend, after all...).

For now, I work around the difficulty with poor man's caching (testing if the objevt exists and executing code only if it does not), but of course I lose consistency, *which is the whole point of using knitr !*

If some kind soul is interested in my problem, I can send him a tarball with the example.

Any hint ?

EDIT : as per rawr demand, here is the *present* state of the minimal .Rnw (I didn't touch the long preamble, in case it would be relevant...) :

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\synctex=1
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
<<include=FALSE>>=
## opts_chunk$set(concordance=TRUE, self.contained=TRUE)
opts_knit$set(concordance=TRUE, self.contained=TRUE)
@ 
%% \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel} %% Français dominant
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Utilité ??
\usepackage{lmodern} %% Polices pour les guillemets ? Oui ! Et
             %% meilleur...
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it} %% Cursives math (distris)
\usepackage{cite} %% Biblios !
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{rotating} %% Pour \sidewaysxxx. et rotations dans les tables.
\usepackage{float} %% pour utiliser la position "H" des tables
\usepackage{subfig} %% Pour les légendes des sous-figures
%% \usepackage{subcaption} %% Mieux ?
\usepackage{hyperref} %% Signets dans le PDF. Doit venir en dernier,
\usepackage{sagetex} %% sauf si on veut l'interfaçage avec Sage,
%                      %% qui doit être *APRÈS*!!!
% \usepackage{emaxima} %% Si l'on veut utiliser maxima...

\title{Minimal reproductible example exhibiting a caching problem with \textsl{knitr} caching}
\author{Emmanuel Charpentier}
\date{June 4, 2014}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \emph{}
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage

%% My usual setup, adapted to each main (noweb) file name via emacs.

<<KnitrSetup, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
render_sweave()
library(Cairo)
##
opts_chunk$set(eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, dev=c('cairo_pdf', 'cairo_ps'),
               fig.ext=c('pdf', 'eps'), fig.path="figureTmp/",
               cache=TRUE, cache.path="cacheTmp/",
               fig.width=5, fig.height=4, ## Pouces (obligatoire)
               out.width="5in", ## 1/1 scale, just in case...
               autodep=TRUE, cache.lazy=FALSE)
@ 

<<LibsSetup, echo=FALSE, results="hide">>=
## libaries used in the rest of the text.
require(xtable)
require(MatchIt)
@ 

Start compilation with a citation\cite{rosenbaum_central_1983} to appease \textsl{knit2pdf}\dots

<<Lecture1, echo=FALSE, results="hide", cache.extra=file.info("Pts.csv")$mtime>>=
## Read data
## On lit à partir du jeu que j'ai mis au propre
Pts<-within(read.csv("Pts.csv", sep=";", dec=","),
            PtId<-factor(as.character(PtId),levels=PtId))
@ 

<<Lecture2, echo=FALSE, results="hide", cache.extra=file.info("Data.csv")$mtime>>=
## Read data (bis)
Data.long<-within(read.csv("Data.csv", dec=",", sep=";"),
                  PtId<-factor(as.character(PtId),levels=levels(Pts$PtId)))
@ 

<<Variations, echo=FALSE, results="hide">>=
Variations<-within(reshape(Data.long, idvar=c("PtId", "Var"),
                           timevar="T", direction="wide"),
                   Variation<-Val.Ap-Val.Av)
Vars<-merge(Pts,Variations)
@ 


<<Appariement1, echo=FALSE, results="hide", message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
## Create the (wide) pre-treatment dataset
PreTtt<-local({
    foo<-merge(Pts[,c("PtId","Groupe","Sexe","Age.T0","Durée")],
               within(reshape(Variations[,c("PtId", "Var", "Val.Av")],
                              idvar="PtId",
                              timevar="Var",
                              direction="wide"), {
                                  PtId<-factor(as.character(PtId),
                                               levels=levels(Pts$PtId))
                              }))
    foo<-within(foo, {
        Ttt<-(Groupe=="Ttt")
        SexeF<-(Sexe=="F")
    })
    foo<-foo[!is.na(foo$Age.T0),
             setdiff(names(foo),
                     c("Groupe","Sexe"))]
    names(foo)<-gsub("Val\\.Av\\.","",names(foo))
    row.names(foo)<-foo$PtId
    foo
})
@ 

This is the problematic chunk. It re-runs in every compilation.

<<Appariement2, echo=FALSE, results="hide", message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
## Do pairing on pre-treatment variables
## NB : matchit is noisy...
## Poor man's attempt at caching (commented out)
## if (!("Pairing" %in% ls())) {
Pairing<-local({
    foo<-matchit(Ttt~Apx.Sup.x+Sn.x+BL.Sup.x+L.Sup.y+Prn.y+Age.T0+ANB+
                 BL.Sup.y+L.Inf.y+SexeF+Apx.Sup.x+Sn.x+Durée+Apx.Inf.x+
                 Pog.Os.x+Pog.Cut.x+SLM.x+Sn.x+L.Sup.y+SNA+BL.Inf.y+SLM.y,
                 data=PreTtt[!is.na(PreTtt$Age.T0),],
                 method="genetic", pop.size=500,
                 estimand="ATE",
                 discard="both")
    foo
})
## } ## end of caching
@ 

Pairing done.

%% Still untested : pairing summary :

%% <<Appariement3, echo=FALSE, results="hide", message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
%% ## Balance de l'appariement
%% PairingSum<-summary(Pairing,
%%         addlvariables=PreTtt[!is.na(PreTtt$Age.T0),
%%             setdiff(names(PreTtt),
%%                     c("PtId","Ttt",
%%                       do.call(c,
%%                               lapply(as.character(Pairing$formula[[3]]),
%%                                      function(x) {
%%                                          strsplit(x,
%%                                                   " + ",
%%                                                   fixed=TRUE)[[1]]}))[-1]))],
%%              standardize=TRUE)
%% @ 


\clearpage


\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\bibliography{Tmp}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-master: "Tmp"
%%% End:
```

---

Feeling better ? ;-)

Comment: You could post the code to your question..? -rawr, 1645 pts, HS diploma 2005, highest average in algebra award, 6th grade

Comment: @rawr why are mentioning you algebra level?(bad copy/paste)?

Comment: So are you saying that any combination of knitr/matchit will cause this error or do you think it's really specific to your data. It seems unlikely to be specific to your data so you should be able to create a reproducible example with dummy data that runs much more quickly. If you can't isolate and reduce the problem, you haven't really found the problem.

Comment: MrFlick : I tihnk that the issue is procedure-related, and notr *directly* data related. Bit since Matching is highly data-driven, what it does effectively depends on the data ; to reproduce thje problem, you should have the relevant data. Furthermore, MatchIt is somewhat picky about what data it accepts or not. Simulating all of this correctly would probably need more work than granted.

Comment: agstudy : rawr was probably picking at my signature .. :-) (He was right, by the way : that was a (useless) reflex...).

Comment: I agree with your comment about "poor man's caching", but I do think that for big cases like this it would be wise to move to a more robust setup (e.g. a Makefile/knitr/R batch file bundle) ...

Comment: Ben Bolker : you're probably right. But I would lose the extraordinary interactivity allowed by the emacs/ESS/R/AucTeX/knitr combination (the live R session is an incredible help to coders as bad as I am ...). [ Furthermore, this propensity score gamut is, to me, an interim solution : I'd rather use a Bayesian setting based on the probability that two patients' pre-treatment data are issued from the same patient or not. As far as I know, no one has developped such an idea until now. ]